# Is it possible to compare two empty Runnable for equality?

Tags: java, equals, runnable

I have a method which returns a `Runnable`. In certain situations, it will return an empty runnable (`() -> {}`) and I would like to test that these situations are well respected.

Hence, I was thinking to do some simple unit tests such as:

```
private static final Runnable EMPTY = () -> {};

@Test
public void test() {
    Runnable action = myObject.myMethod(myParameters);
    assertEquals(EMPTY, action);
}
```

The above clearly doesn't work since `Runnable` is a functional interface, and I guess that would be up to me to override the `equals` method eventually or else I will just call the one of the superclass `Object` and hence I would fail my assertion.

On one hand, I understand it's hard (or simply impossible?) to test equality of two runnables which may potentially contain anything.
On the other hand, I would really like to test just if the runnable is empty, nothing else.

So for now, I have created a `public static final Runnable EMPTY` on the `myObject` class which I return when I need:

```
public class MyObject {
    public static final Runnable EMPTY = () -> {};
    
    public Runnable myMethod(MyParameters myParameters) {
        if (something) {
            return EMPTY;
        }
        //...
        if (somethingElse) {
            return EMPTY;
        }
        //...
        return anotherRunnable;
    }
}
```

and then I reference this instance from the tests, which works fine for a limited number of tests:

```
assertEquals(MyObject.EMPTY, action);
```

But the `Runnable` may one day also be provided from the external, which means I would have no control on the fact that the empty runnable is exactly my static empty instance, and in this case I would really need to know whether the provided runnable is empty or not.

Any idea? Am I asking for something impossible?

Comment: Your examples only deal with an "empty" `Runnable`, i.e. one whose `run` method does nothing. I assume you want to test equality of two `Runnable` objects where both objects have a non-empty `run` method. In such a case, what determines whether the two `Runnable` objects are equal? Will they both have the exact, same code?

Comment: @Abra well ideally, but actually I may be already pretty happy if I was able to simply understand the runnable is empty and ignore any other case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: **it is impossible**.

Long answer: It is possible, but you don't want to do it because you have to disassembly class file for said `Runnable` and check method body. Which is too much effort. There should be easier way to achieve result you want.

Comment: I see, I guess I was expecting this answer but just wanting to make sure. Thanks!